# Открытие URL с POST запросом android

Tags: php, java, android, post

Нужно открыть Адрес с использование POST запроса на Android через браузер, перенаправив пользователя из приложения. Не получается этого сделать. Нашёл [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24496263/12852336), но он не работает у меня. Подскажите, что делать и куда копать?

Comment: а зачем через browser а не напрямую?